# How to directly access items inside my WebGrid

Tags: asp.net, razor, webgrid, razorengine

I have the following asp.net webgrid inside my razor view:-

```
@model SkillManagement.Models.PagedList<SkillManagement.Models.Staff>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="well">
   @using (Html.BeginForm("index", null, FormMethod.Get))
    {
      <div class="row">There are @Model.TotalRecords item.</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="input-group">

                    <input type="text"
                        name="filter"
                        value="@ViewBag.filter"
                        class="form-control"
                        style="display: inline"
                        placeholder="Search by First & Last Name" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go</button>
                    </span>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right col-lg-1">   
                <a class="btn btn-success" data-modal="" href="/Staff/Create" id="btnCreate">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>      
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-top:17px;">
            @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(
                        canPage: true,
                        rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
                        canSort: true,
                        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

            grid.Bind(Model.Content, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

            @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },   // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: grid.Columns(
              grid.Column("FirstName", Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content.FirstOrDefault().FirstName).ToString()),
              grid.Column("LastName", Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content.FirstOrDefault().LastName).ToString()),
              grid.Column("PrimaryRole", Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content.FirstOrDefault().PrimaryRole).ToString()),
              grid.Column("SecondaryRole", Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content.FirstOrDefault().SecondaryRole).ToString()),
              grid.Column("Skill",canSort:false,format:

                 @<text>
            @foreach (var c in item.SkillLevelStaffs)
{
    @c.Skill.Name;
}


                   </text>),
              grid.Column("Actions",canSort:false,format:

                 @<text>



                   <a data-modal='' href="/Staff/details/@item.StaffID"   id="@item.StaffID" title="Details"> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'> </span> </a>
                  <a data-modal='' href="/Staff/edit/@item.StaffID"   id="@item.StaffID" title="Edit"> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'> </span> </a>
                   @if(item.ISActive){<a data-modal='' href="/Staff/Deactivate/@item.StaffID"   id="@item.StaffID" title="Deactivate"> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-alert'> </span> </a>}
            else if(!item.ISActive){<a data-modal='' href="/Staff/delete/@item.StaffID"   id="@item.StaffID" title="Delete"> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span> </a>}
                </text>
                       )

            ));
            }


        </div>
    }
</div>


<!-- modal placeholder-->
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") 
<script src="~/Scripts/skillmanagementgrid.js"></script>
}
```

I have defined the following model:-

```
    public class PagedList<T>
    {
        public List<T> Content { get; set; }

        public Int32 CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public Int32 PageSize { get; set; }
        public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
        public bool OnlyActive { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages
        {
            get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalRecords / PageSize); }
        }
    }
}
```

now as shown inside my view if i want to reference an item inside the grid i need to use FirstOrDefualt as follow:-

```
Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content.FirstOrDefault().LastName)
```

so can anyone adivce what are the approaches i can follow to directly access the model items without having to call FirstOrDefault ?

second question. at the top of my view i need to mentioned the full project name as follow:-

```
 @model SkillManagement.Models.PagedList<SkillManagement.Models.Staff>
```

but my question is how i can just declare the model as follow:-

```
 @model `PagedList<SkillManagement.Models.Staff>`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can access properties of an object inside a List<> without being specific about which object you want from the list. List can contains more than one object, and to access any object it is required to mention the index of that element. However if you are storing only one element in your list then I would suggest to change your List to just T.
For example,

```
public class PagedList<T>
{
    public T Content { get; set; }

    public Int32 CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public Int32 PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    public bool OnlyActive { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages
    {
        get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalRecords / PageSize); }
    }
}
```

For your second question, use @using statement. For example,

```
@using SkillManagement.Models
@model PagedList<SkillManagement.Models.Staff>
```

I hope this answers your questions.

Comment: the PagedList for sure will contain more than one item becuase it is used to display list of data inside the grid.... so if the way i am doing thing Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content.FirstOrDefault().LastName) sound valid ?

Comment: second question , i think there is way to even remove "@using SkillManagement.Models" from the top of the view ,, but i can not remember it . because on the defualt scaffolding template you can only mentioned something such as IEnumerable<Applicationname.Models.TestModel>